# js it's not running in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm migrating my laravel project to ionos hosting, but js it's not working, I think I have it all ok.
in my localhost is working fine.
not working local files and CDN
I am stuck.
and I have these errors:
[image]

Could you help me, please?

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>Sertek</title>
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link href="{{ asset('argon') }}/img/brand/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png">
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Icons -->
        <link href="{{ asset('argon') }}/vendor/nucleo/css/nucleo.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('argon') }}/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Argon CSS -->
        <link type="text/css" href="{{ asset('argon') }}/css/argon.css?v=1.0.0" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.semanticui.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css">
    </head>
    <body class="{{ $class ?? 'bg-default' }}">


        <script src="{{ asset('argon') }}/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('argon') }}/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/esm/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Argon JS -->
        <script src="{{ asset('argon') }}/js/argon.js?v=1.0.0"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script>
         window.onload = function exampleFunction() { 
            console.log('The Script will load now.'); //this works
        } 
    </script>
            @stack('js')

    </body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, my local jquery not working fine. I changed

```html
<script src="{{ asset('argon') }}/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
```

to

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```